# How to convert csv file to JSON file by using python

Tags: python, json, csv

I need to convert a csv file into a JSON object (preferably using Python)

Input file is :

```
**Jun 28 23:59:56 MUM-NM-FG-FW/MUM-NM-FG-FW date=2014-06-28 time=23:59:59 devname=MUM-NM-FG-FW-PRI device_id=FG300C3911600511 log_id=0038000004 type=traffic subtype=other pri=notice vd=Sify-VDOM src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX src_port=60276 src_int="port5" dst=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 


Jun 28 23:59:56 MUM-NM-FG-FW/MUM-NM-FG-FW date=2014-06-28 time=23:59:59 devname=MUM-NM-FG-FW-PRI device_id=FG300C3911600511 log_id=0038000004 type=traffic subtype=other pri=notice vd=Sify-VDOM src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  src_port=60277 src_int="port5" dst=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX**
```

Result is like:

```
{"date": "2014-06-28","time": "22:59:59","devname": "MUM-NM-FG-FW-PRI","device_id": "FG300C3911600511","log_id": "0038000004","type": "traffic","subtype": "other","pri": "notice","vd": "Sify-VDOM","src": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX","src_port": "60276","src_int": "port5","dst": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" }

{"date": "2014-06-28","time": "22:59:59","devname": "MUM-NM-FG-FW-PRI","device_id": "FG300C3911600511","log_id": "0038000004","type": "traffic","subtype": "other","pri": "notice","vd": "Sify-VDOM","src": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX","src_port": "60277","src_int": "port5","dst": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" }
```

Please help on this.

Comment: use csv.Dictreader and json.dump on the generated dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the csv and json modules in python.
Below a link that explain how to do it:
http://www.idiotinside.com/2015/09/18/csv-json-pretty-print-python/

Comment: my csv file is key value pair. please look into the data once.